# LSTM seq2seq model in R does not seem to use trained model for predictions

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, seq2seq

For a project i'm trying to create a function that can "translate" names written in latin characters into IPA (phonetic).

I've found an example of a sequence2sequence model in TensorFlow for R that does character-level machine translation: https://github.com/rstudio/keras/blob/main/vignettes/examples/lstm_seq2seq.R

I'm training it using data that's generated using this online service: https://clarin.phonetik.uni-muenchen.de/BASWebServices/interface/Grapheme2Phoneme

My current script is here below. Don't read it all, i'll highlight the relevant bits for me underneath. I've included the entire script just for reference. The training data can be downloaded here: https://file.io/ut4IkeLRqyIa

```
library(keras)
library(data.table)
library(stringr)

# Clear the workspace
rm(list = ls())

# Set initial parameters
batch_size = 64  # Batch size for training.
epochs = 3  # Number of epochs to train for.
latent_dim = 256  # Latent dimensionality of the encoding space.
num_samples = 3500  # Number of samples to train on.

# Load the training data
load("./data_seq2seq/ipa_abc_ENG.rda")

## Vectorize the data.
input_texts  <- dataset[[2]]
target_texts <- paste0('\t',dataset[[1]],'\n')
input_texts  <- lapply( input_texts, function(s) strsplit(s, split="")[[1]])
target_texts <- lapply( target_texts, function(s) strsplit(s, split="")[[1]])

input_characters  <- sort(unique(unlist(input_texts)))
target_characters <- sort(unique(unlist(target_texts)))
num_encoder_tokens <- length(input_characters)
num_decoder_tokens <- length(target_characters)
max_encoder_seq_length <- max(sapply(input_texts,length))
max_decoder_seq_length <- max(sapply(target_texts,length))

cat('Number of samples:', length(input_texts),'\n')
cat('Number of unique input tokens:', num_encoder_tokens,'\n')
cat('Number of unique output tokens:', num_decoder_tokens,'\n')
cat('Max sequence length for inputs:', max_encoder_seq_length,'\n')
cat('Max sequence length for outputs:', max_decoder_seq_length,'\n')

input_token_index  <- 1:length(input_characters)
names(input_token_index) <- input_characters
target_token_index <- 1:length(target_characters)
names(target_token_index) <- target_characters
encoder_input_data <- array(
  0, dim = c(length(input_texts), max_encoder_seq_length, num_encoder_tokens))
decoder_input_data <- array(
  0, dim = c(length(input_texts), max_decoder_seq_length, num_decoder_tokens))
decoder_target_data <- array(
  0, dim = c(length(input_texts), max_decoder_seq_length, num_decoder_tokens))

for(i in 1:length(input_texts)) {
  d1 <- sapply( input_characters, function(x) { as.integer(x == input_texts[[i]]) })
  encoder_input_data[i,1:nrow(d1),] <- d1
  d2 <- sapply( target_characters, function(x) { as.integer(x == target_texts[[i]]) })
  decoder_input_data[i,1:nrow(d2),] <- d2
  d3 <- sapply( target_characters, function(x) { as.integer(x == target_texts[[i]][-1]) })
  decoder_target_data[i,1:nrow(d3),] <- d3
}

##----------------------------------------------------------------------
## Create the model
##----------------------------------------------------------------------

## Define an input sequence and process it.
encoder_inputs  <- layer_input(shape=list(NULL,num_encoder_tokens))
encoder         <- layer_lstm(units=latent_dim, return_state=TRUE)
encoder_results <- encoder_inputs %>% encoder
## We discard `encoder_outputs` and only keep the states.
encoder_states  <- encoder_results[2:3]

## Set up the decoder, using `encoder_states` as initial state.
decoder_inputs  <- layer_input(shape=list(NULL, num_decoder_tokens))
## We set up our decoder to return full output sequences,
## and to return internal states as well. We don't use the
## return states in the training model, but we will use them in inference.
decoder_lstm    <- layer_lstm(units=latent_dim, return_sequences=TRUE,
                              return_state=TRUE, stateful=FALSE)
decoder_results <- decoder_lstm(decoder_inputs, initial_state=encoder_states)
decoder_dense   <- layer_dense(units=num_decoder_tokens, activation='softmax')
decoder_outputs <- decoder_dense(decoder_results[[1]])

## Define the model that will turn
## `encoder_input_data` & `decoder_input_data` into `decoder_target_data`
model <- keras_model( inputs = list(encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs),
                      outputs = decoder_outputs )

## Compile model
model %>% compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy')

## Run model
model %>% fit( list(encoder_input_data, decoder_input_data), decoder_target_data,
               batch_size=batch_size,
               epochs=epochs,
               validation_split=0.2)

## Below the model is saved. It's never referenced anywhere else in the code anymore, however.
## I'm unsure how to load it into a function that uses the model.

## Save model
#save_model_hdf5(model,'./data_seq2seq/s2s_abc_ipa_EN.h5')
#save_model_weights_hdf5(model,'./data_seq2seq/s2s-wt_abc_ipa_EN.h5')

##model <- load_model_hdf5('s2s.h5')
##load_model_weights_hdf5(model,'s2s-wt.h5')

##----------------------------------------------------------------------
## Next: inference mode (sampling).
##----------------------------------------------------------------------
## Here's the drill:
## 1) encode input and retrieve initial decoder state
## 2) run one step of decoder with this initial state
## and a "start of sequence" token as target.
## Output will be the next target token
## 3) Repeat with the current target token and current states

## Define sampling models
encoder_model <-  keras_model(encoder_inputs, encoder_states)
decoder_state_input_h <- layer_input(shape=latent_dim)
decoder_state_input_c <- layer_input(shape=latent_dim)
decoder_states_inputs <- c(decoder_state_input_h, decoder_state_input_c)
decoder_results <- decoder_lstm(decoder_inputs, initial_state=decoder_states_inputs)
decoder_states  <- decoder_results[2:3]
decoder_outputs <- decoder_dense(decoder_results[[1]])
decoder_model   <- keras_model(
  inputs  = c(decoder_inputs, decoder_states_inputs),
  outputs = c(decoder_outputs, decoder_states))

## Reverse-lookup token index to decode sequences back to
## something readable.
reverse_input_char_index  <- as.character(input_characters)
reverse_target_char_index <- as.character(target_characters)

decode_sequence <- function(input_seq) {
  ## Encode the input as state vectors.
  states_value <- predict(encoder_model, input_seq)
  
  ## Generate empty target sequence of length 1.
  target_seq <- array(0, dim=c(1, 1, num_decoder_tokens))
  ## Populate the first character of target sequence with the start character.
  target_seq[1, 1, target_token_index['\t']] <- 1.
  
  ## Sampling loop for a batch of sequences
  ## (to simplify, here we assume a batch of size 1).
  stop_condition = FALSE
  decoded_sentence = ''
  maxiter = max_decoder_seq_length
  niter = 1
  while (!stop_condition && niter < maxiter) {
    
    ## output_tokens, h, c = decoder_model.predict([target_seq] + states_value)
    decoder_predict <- predict(decoder_model, c(list(target_seq), states_value))
    output_tokens <- decoder_predict[[1]]
    
    ## Sample a token
    sampled_token_index <- which.max(output_tokens[1, 1, ])
    sampled_char <- reverse_target_char_index[sampled_token_index]
    decoded_sentence <-  paste0(decoded_sentence, sampled_char)
    decoded_sentence
    
    ## Exit condition: either hit max length
    ## or find stop character.
    if (sampled_char == '\n' ||
        length(decoded_sentence) > max_decoder_seq_length) {
      stop_condition = TRUE
    }
    
    ## Update the target sequence (of length 1).
    ## target_seq = np.zeros((1, 1, num_decoder_tokens))
    target_seq[1, 1, ] <- 0
    target_seq[1, 1, sampled_token_index] <- 1.
    
    ## Update states
    h <- decoder_predict[[2]]
    c <- decoder_predict[[3]]
    states_value = list(h, c)
    niter <- niter + 1
  }    
  return(decoded_sentence)
}

for (seq_index in 1:10) {
  ## Take one sequence (part of the training test)
  ## for trying out decoding.
  input_seq = encoder_input_data[seq_index,,,drop=FALSE]
  decoded_sentence = decode_sequence(input_seq)
  target_sentence <- gsub("\t|\n","",paste(target_texts[[seq_index]],collapse=''))
  input_sentence  <- paste(input_texts[[seq_index]],collapse='')
  cat('-\n')
  cat('Input sentence  : ', input_sentence,'\n')
  cat('Target sentence : ', target_sentence,'\n')
  cat('Decoded sentence: ', decoded_sentence,'\n')
}

# I wrote this custom function to test the predictions
# This was reverse engineered from the above code
decode_string <- function(x){
  x_decode <- unlist(strsplit(x, ""))
  d1_input <- sapply( input_characters, function(x) { as.integer(x == x_decode) })
  d1 <- array(data = 0, dim = c(1,23,27))
  d1[1, 1:nrow(d1_input),] <- d1_input
  decode_sequence(d1)
}
```

The model is trained and then saved in this piece of the code:

```
## Define the model that will turn
## `encoder_input_data` & `decoder_input_data` into `decoder_target_data`
model <- keras_model( inputs = list(encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs),
                      outputs = decoder_outputs )

## Compile model
model %>% compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy')

## Run model
model %>% fit( list(encoder_input_data, decoder_input_data), decoder_target_data,
               batch_size=batch_size,
               epochs=epochs,
               validation_split=0.2)

## Save model
save_model_hdf5(model,'s2s.h5')
save_model_weights_hdf5(model,'s2s-wt.h5')
```

I would expect the object "model" to be used in the prediction process.
Instead, it creates an encoder model and decoder model seemingly from scratch (?):

```
encoder_model <-  keras_model(encoder_inputs, encoder_states)
decoder_state_input_h <- layer_input(shape=latent_dim)
decoder_state_input_c <- layer_input(shape=latent_dim)
decoder_states_inputs <- c(decoder_state_input_h, decoder_state_input_c)
decoder_results <- decoder_lstm(decoder_inputs, initial_state=decoder_states_inputs)
decoder_states  <- decoder_results[2:3]
decoder_outputs <- decoder_dense(decoder_results[[1]])
decoder_model   <- keras_model(
  inputs  = c(decoder_inputs, decoder_states_inputs),
  outputs = c(decoder_outputs, decoder_states))

## Reverse-lookup token index to decode sequences back to
## something readable.
reverse_input_char_index  <- as.character(input_characters)
reverse_target_char_index <- as.character(target_characters)
```

And then it uses those to make the predictions:

```
decode_sequence <- function(input_seq) {
  ## Encode the input as state vectors.
  states_value <- predict(encoder_model, input_seq)
  
  ## Generate empty target sequence of length 1.
  target_seq <- array(0, dim=c(1, 1, num_decoder_tokens))
  ## Populate the first character of target sequence with the start character.
  target_seq[1, 1, target_token_index['\t']] <- 1.
  
  ## Sampling loop for a batch of sequences
  ## (to simplify, here we assume a batch of size 1).
  stop_condition = FALSE
  decoded_sentence = ''
  maxiter = max_decoder_seq_length
  niter = 1
  while (!stop_condition && niter < maxiter) {
    
    ## output_tokens, h, c = decoder_model.predict([target_seq] + states_value)
    decoder_predict <- predict(decoder_model, c(list(target_seq), states_value))
    output_tokens <- decoder_predict[[1]]
    
    ## Sample a token
    sampled_token_index <- which.max(output_tokens[1, 1, ])
    sampled_char <- reverse_target_char_index[sampled_token_index]
    decoded_sentence <-  paste0(decoded_sentence, sampled_char)
    decoded_sentence
    
    ## Exit condition: either hit max length
    ## or find stop character.
    if (sampled_char == '\n' ||
        length(decoded_sentence) > max_decoder_seq_length) {
      stop_condition = TRUE
    }
    
    ## Update the target sequence (of length 1).
    ## target_seq = np.zeros((1, 1, num_decoder_tokens))
    target_seq[1, 1, ] <- 0
    target_seq[1, 1, sampled_token_index] <- 1.
    
    ## Update states
    h <- decoder_predict[[2]]
    c <- decoder_predict[[3]]
    states_value = list(h, c)
    niter <- niter + 1
  }    
  return(decoded_sentence)
}

for (seq_index in 1:10) {
  ## Take one sequence (part of the training test)
  ## for trying out decoding.
  input_seq = encoder_input_data[seq_index,,,drop=FALSE]
  decoded_sentence = decode_sequence(input_seq)
  target_sentence <- gsub("\t|\n","",paste(target_texts[[seq_index]],collapse=''))
  input_sentence  <- paste(input_texts[[seq_index]],collapse='')
  cat('-\n')
  cat('Input sentence  : ', input_sentence,'\n')
  cat('Target sentence : ', target_sentence,'\n')
  cat('Decoded sentence: ', decoded_sentence,'\n')
}
```

What am i not understanding here? The final for-loop shows me results that clearly improve when i train the model for more epochs. But when i load the model from scratch, i have no way of loading it into a predictor. How do i use the trained model for translation?

EDIT:
So there are 3 keras models being referenced in the script. The "main" model, which is just named "model", and an "encoder_model" and "decoder_model". I've run summary() on each of them and got these results:

[image]
[image]
[image]

It looks like the "main" model contains all the shape and state information that is required for the encoder and decoder models. How can i extract the encoder model from the main model? And the decoder?

Comment: I can't download your data, it says: `The transfer you requested has been deleted.`.

Comment: It might have expired. I've reuploaded the data and edited the link: https://file.io/ut4IkeLRqyIa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the layers inside a trained model you can use the function `get_layer`. To get the input you can use $input and for output use $output like this:

```
> model
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                           Output Shape               Param #       Connected to                             
==========================================================================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)                   [(None, None, 37)]         0             []                                       
 input_2 (InputLayer)                   [(None, None, 29)]         0             []                                       
 lstm (LSTM)                            [(None, 256),              301056        ['input_1[0][0]']                        
                                         (None, 256),                                                                     
                                         (None, 256)]                                                                     
 lstm_1 (LSTM)                          [(None, None, 256),        292864        ['input_2[0][0]',                        
                                         (None, 256),                             'lstm[0][1]',                           
                                         (None, 256)]                             'lstm[0][2]']                           
 dense (Dense)                          (None, None, 29)           7453          ['lstm_1[0][0]']                         
==========================================================================================================================
Total params: 601,373
Trainable params: 601,373
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
> encoder_model
Model: "model_1"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                                         Output Shape                                     Param #            
==========================================================================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)                                 [(None, None, 37)]                               0                  
 lstm (LSTM)                                          [(None, 256),                                    301056             
                                                       (None, 256),                                                       
                                                       (None, 256)]                                                       
==========================================================================================================================
Total params: 301,056
Trainable params: 301,056
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Code with `get_layer`:

```
> # encoder model
> keras_model(inputs = get_layer(model, 'input_1')$input,
+             outputs = get_layer(model, 'lstm')$output)
Model: "model_15"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                                         Output Shape                                     Param #            
==========================================================================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)                                 [(None, None, 37)]                               0                  
 lstm (LSTM)                                          [(None, 256),                                    301056             
                                                       (None, 256),                                                       
                                                       (None, 256)]                                                       
==========================================================================================================================
Total params: 301,056
Trainable params: 301,056
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: thanks, that works! For the decoder_model i tried to reverse engineer this and got the following code: ```decoder_model2   <- keras_model(
  inputs  = c(get_layer(model, 'input_2')$input, decoder_states_inputs),
  outputs = c(get_layer(model, 'dense')$output, get_layer(model, 'lstm_1')$output))``` but this gives me an error saying "Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor"... did i interpret this wrong?